# How to convert array of bytes to FileImageSource?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want to assign an image to button? I have an array of bytes which represents an image. But I don't know how to convert it to the `FileImageSource`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do does not seem to be possible. There is no way to achieve this using `FileImageSource` directly, no matter casting or other options.

For `Button.Image` you can only use images stored as resources in your platform projects: `Resources folder in iOS, Resources/Drawable folder in Android, and application root in WinPhone`. These images can be loaded in the button as follows:

```
someButton.Image = ImageSource.FromFile("imageName.png");
```

or

```
someButton.Image = "imageName.png";
```

Check out the `Custom Renderers` (see [docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/)). Make sure to also check [this thread](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21301/image-property-on-the-button).

Comment: No. `ImageSource` is not a `FileImageSource` which I'm looking for.